# sklearn SVM custom kernel raise ValueError: X.shape[0] should be equal to X.shape[1]

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, classification, svm

i'm trying to implement a custom kernel, precisely the exponential Chi-Squared kernel, to pass as parameter to sklearn svm function, but when i run it the subsequent error is raised :
ValueError: X.shape[0] should be equal to X.shape[1]

I read about the broadcasting operation performed by numpy's functions in order to speedup the computation but i can't manage the error.

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, datasets

# import the iris dataset (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)
iris = datasets.load_iris()
train_features = iris.data[:, :2]  # Here we only use the first two features.
train_labels = iris.target


def my_kernel(x, y):
    gamma = 1
    return np.exp(-gamma * np.divide((x - y) ** 2, x + y))


classifier = svm.SVC(kernel=my_kernel)

classifier = classifier.fit(train_features, train_labels)

print "Train Accuracy : " + str(classifier.score(train_features, train_labels))
```

Any help?

Comment: Well done on a first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Chi-Squared Kernel is already implemented for you (in `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import chi2_kernel`).

Like so

```
from functools import partial

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import chi2_kernel

# import the iris dataset (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)
iris = datasets.load_iris()
train_features = iris.data[:, :2]  # Here we only use the first two features.
train_labels = iris.target

my_chi2_kernel = partial(chi2_kernel, gamma=1)

classifier = svm.SVC(kernel=my_chi2_kernel)

classifier = classifier.fit(train_features, train_labels)

print("Train Accuracy : " + str(classifier.score(train_features, train_labels)))
```

====================

EDIT:

So turns out the question is really about how one can implement the chi square kernel. My shot at this would be:-

```
def my_chi2_kernel(X):
    gamma = 1
    nom = np.power(X[:, np.newaxis] - X, 2)
    denom = X[:, np.newaxis] + X
    # NOTE: We need to fix some entries, since division by 0 is an issue here.
    #       So we take all the index of would be 0 denominator, and fix them.
    zero_denom_idx = denom == 0
    nom[zero_denom_idx] = 0
    denom[zero_denom_idx] = 1

    return np.exp(-gamma * np.sum(nom / denom, axis=len(X.shape)))
```

So in essence `x - y` and `x + y` in OP's attempt is wrong, since it's not pairwise subtraction or addition.

Curiously, the custom version seems to be faster than sklearn's cythonised version (at least for small dataset?)

Comment: Yes but I need to implement it by my own

Comment: How come? The `chi2_kernel` from sklearn is very optimised in performance..

Comment: They requested me to

Comment: ... implement a kernel function by my own and I selected this one. So, I’d like to find a solution to this error and understand better why this error is raised, could be useful also in future contexts. Can you help to figure it out?

Comment: why aren't you using the y array which contains the train labels? when the fit function of svm is called, it pass to the kernel the two array with features and labels and use both for computing

Comment: Can you also explain me how the shape of the result is pushed to (150,150, 2) from:                                                                               X[:, np.newaxis].shape: (150, 1, 2)
y.shape: (150, 2)
X[:, np.newaxis] - y).shape: (150, 150, 2)

Comment: I don't think kernel in SVM does not make use of the labels? It's a "similarity function" over pairs of data points in raw representation.

Comment: As for your other question, I think https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html should help!

Comment: I was trying to use the grid search algorithm provided by sklearn in order to tune the parameters of the custom function but it raise me error. Also with that one provided by functools library raise the same error. Any idea about that?

Comment: Because `sklearn`'s grid search will use `svm.set_params(..)`, the definition of the grid params should be `{'kernel':  [<kernel1>, <kernel2>, ...]}` I don't recall exactly the syntax, but i believe that's that problem.